# document.ready() function not executed, works in dev console

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to simulate a click in a tabbed div when the page loads.

To do this I use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tab_inbox").click();
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, but when I enter this in the dev console on Google chrome, **it does work..**

```
$("#tab_inbox").click();
```

To show the tabs, I use this code:

```
$("#tab_inbox").click(function() {
    $("#othertab").hide();
    $("#tab_inbox").show();
});
```

Anybody knows what's wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using some sort of plugin for the tabs ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using simple show/hide techniques..

Comment: why don't you close it?
")" after rightbrace, is this exactly your code?

Comment: I don't understand how a "click" event is supposed to work for an element that's hidden. How does the user click on it?  If you're just trying to use an event handler to trigger behavior, and "click" isn't particularly important, it would be clearer to use your own made-up custom event name, like "show-tab".

Comment: are your tabs added dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function () {
           $("#tab_inbox").trigger('click'); //do work here
        }, 2500);

});
```

Comment: Same result: works in chrome console, doesn't work when used in $(document).ready(function() { });

Comment: This works! Thanks!! :) 

I still don't get why tough..
(I'll thank you in 30 seconds)

Comment: I guess the DOM elements were not loaded when you were trying to simulate the click....

Comment: 'load' is called when all assets are done loading, including images. 'ready' is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I read in your comment that you're using show/hide techniques and I assume you need the click for an initial display option? If so, hide (or show) your element(s) specifically in the code rather than saying click to hide/show. So

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tab_inbox").hide();
}
```

Or try core JavaScript and use

```
window.onload = function() {
    // code here
}
```

window.onload waits until everything is loaded on your page, while jQuery's .ready() may fire before images and other media are loaded.

Comment: That could be a possible solution, but I'm doing more than just showing the div, it's all inside a massive click-event-handler..

Comment: Then try core javascript window.onload

Answer (score 0):

you can try making your own function with pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('triggerElement').addEventListener('click', funtction(e) {
    document.getElementById('hideElement').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('showElement').style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```